# read all lines from string buffered reader

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have simple client/server program that sends and recieves strings from client to server and vice versa. 
Some string contain newline characters `"n\`", eg `"ERR\nASCII: OK"`

my buffered reader:

```
BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(ConverterSocket.getInputStream()));
```

I am trying to display each line in the string to the user/ client.

I have tried the following for loop:

```
for (line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
```

output (as expected):

```
ERR
ASCII: OK
```

but the loop doesn't end. I have also tried:

```
   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        system.out.println(line)
    }
```

which also doesn't end properly.
How can i print all lines in the string?

Comment: The read loop waits for the next message. If end-of-line is not the end of a message, you should design a protocol so that the read loop knows when to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readLine()` method returns null at end of stream, which doesn't occur until the peer closes the connection.